# search for string in file using an aray elements perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl, file-handling

I have a array which contains set of unique elements my_array=  [aab, abc def, fgh,]
I have a file which containing these elements(repeated also)
I want to count each unique element has how many repetitions if no repetition then count is 1

example of file :

```
i want to have aab but no i dont want abc
i want to have aab but no i dont want def
```

output should be

```
aab - 2
abc - 1
def - 1
```

I tried to search first and print it its not woking

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @my_array;

@my_array =("abc", "aab", "def");
open (my $file, '<', 'filename.txt') or die;
my $value;
foreach $value (@my_array) {
    while(<$file>) {
        if ($_ =~ /$value/){
            print "found : $value\n"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried 2nd method

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @my_array;

@my_array =("abc", "aab", "def");

open (my $file, '<', 'filename.txt') or die;
while (<$file>) {
    my $k=0;
    if ($_ =~ /$my_array[$k]/) {
        print "$my_array[$k]”;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not added the full code assume array containing all values

Comment: You should add small, complete code samples that people can copy paste and try to run to demonstrate the problem. Also, you should use indentation, it really makes things easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Sample input data does not specify if `lookup` words repeat in the line or not.

Following demo code assumes that `lookup` words do not repeat in the line.

If this statement above does not true then the line should be [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) into tokens and each token must be inspected to get correct count of `lookup` words.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my(%count,@lookup);

@lookup =('abc', 'aab', 'def');

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    for ( @lookup ) {
        $count{$_}++ if $line =~ /\b$_\b/;
    }
}

say Dumper(\%count);

exit 0;

__DATA__
i want to have aab but no i dont want abc
i want to have aab but no i dont want def
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'aab' => 2,
          'abc' => 1,
          'def' => 1
        };
```

Comment: If you do `++ for $line =~ /../g` instead of `if` you can skip the warning about multiple matches. Possibly it should also use the quotemeta `\Q..\E` escape.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of the [`Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS) module for performing [efficient searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) for multiple strings at once. An example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS;

my @words = qw/abc aab def/;
my $aho = Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS->new(\@words);

my %counts;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $counts{$_}++ for $aho->matches($line);
}

for my $word (@words) {
    printf "%s - %d\n", $word, $counts{$word}//1;
}

__DATA__
i want to have aab but no i dont want abc
i want to have aab but no i dont want def
```

outputs

```
abc - 1
aab - 2
def - 1
```

The `$counts{$word}//1` bit in the output will give you a 1 if that word doesn't exist in the hash because it wasn't encountered in the text.

Comment: Yes this is fast, I did a comparison between AhoCorasick and some other approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092036/2173773)

Comment: In which I also suggested the module, heh. Told you I liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Can build an alternation pattern from the keywords and so match all that are on the line in one regex run, then populate a frequency hash with the matches

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @keywords = qw(aab abc def fgh);

my $re_w = join '|', @keywords; 

my %freq;

while (<>) {
    ++$freq{$_} for /($re_w)/g
}

say Dumper \%freq;
```

The [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads line by line the files with names given on the command line, so the program is used as `prog.pl file`.  (Or open the file "manually" in the program.)

The `for` loop imposes list context on its expression, so that regex returns the list of matches (captures), as the match operator does in the list context, and the `++$freq{$_}` expression works with them one at a time.

The code counts all instances of keywords that repeat on a line.  If that's not desired please clarify (can add a call to `List::Util::uniq` before feeding the list of matches to the `for` loop).

There are a number of other details that may need closer attention.

One example: if there are overlapping keywords, which one takes precedence? For instance, with keywords `the` and `there`, once the word `there` is encountered in the text should it be matched by `there` or by `the`? If it is `there` then keywords in the alternation pattern should be ordered from longest to shortest,

```
my $re_w = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } @w;
```

Please clarify if there are additional considerations.